# Manipulate local varible in helper method AND return another value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I extract the conditionals below into a method?

I want both to set a new value to the variable AND return the iterated item's value.

```
my_variable = 0

collection_one.each do |item|
  if item.some_attribute != my_variable 
    my_variable = item.some_attribute
    item.some_attribute
  end
  # do other stuff
end

collection_two.each do |item|
  if item.some_attribute != my_variable 
    my_variable = item.some_attribute
    item.some_attribute
  end
  # do other stuff
end
```

Comment: you want to return an array?

Comment: i tried to return `[item.some_attribute, my_variable]`, but the new `my_variable` value is not persisting to the next time the method is run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `my_variable` will not persist in the next iteration since it's being overridden inside first `each` method. For that you can do:

```
my_variable = 0

collection_one.each_wth_object do |item, obj|
  if item.some_attribute != my_variable 
    obj << [item.some_attribute, my_variable]
    my_variable = item.some_attribute
    item.some_attribute
  end
  # do other stuff
end

my_variable = 0 # define it again

collection_two.each_with_object([]) do |item, obj|
  if item.some_attribute != my_variable 
    obj << [item.some_attribute, my_variable]
    my_variable = item.some_attribute
    item.some_attribute
  end
  # do other stuff
end
```

here `obj` will hold the values of different array of array: `[[item.some_attribute, my_variable], [...], [..],..]` inside each `each_with_object`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above has already been provided.

My suggestion is to write methods - inside them you can guarantee the outcome.

If you need a persistent variable you could use an @ivar.

Like, change:

```
my_variable = 0
```

to

```
@my_variable = 0
```

And everywhere else you have my_variable, replace with @my_variable. Then it
should work.

You could also abuse an ARRAY constant to store the results there.

```
ARRAY_RESULT_VALUES = []

ARRAY_RESULT_VALUES << result_from_first_method
ARRAY_RESULT_VALUES << result_from_second_method
```

Try to decide which path you want to go first. Of course a 
$global variable is also possible but not necessary and quite
ugly.

You could also try to keep using a local variable but you already
discovered the problem there:

"i tried to return [item.some_attribute, my_variable], but the new my_variable value is not persisting to the next time the method is run.. –  Numbers 1 hour ago"
(By the way, you wrote method, but in the code you showed above you never
used **def** ?)

That makes sense because the local variable, as the name implies,
will be only local to the scope/method it was bound to. In your
case it exists on the first run, on subsequent runs of the same
file it would be re-set to nil.

I think an @ivar would be the best solution really.
Then you can store the result in a more persistent variable.